# Do you know a way to automatically enter and contain a background-image inside a css clip-path?

Tags: html, css

Here are my demos:

- *clip_background_contain [single]* => https://codepen.io/joondoe/pen/ExxGdZz?editors=0100
- *clip_background_contain [container]* => https://codepen.io/joondoe/pen/qBBLJMb

I will present you the snippets of the clip_background_contain [single]'s demo. My problem is that currently I am centering the background inside the clip-path using percentages. It is rather an approximate method and I wonder if there is some automatic, mathematical methods to achieve this result?.

For example something like a `center`'s property, also you will spot that the *contain* property seems to make my background disappear in *clip_background_contain [container]*.

Here is my *clip_background_contain [single]*'s css snippet:

```css
.circle_clip{
/*   padding:10vh; */
  width:50vw;
  height:50vh;
  background:black url(https://www.wallpaperup.com/uploads/wallpapers/2018/02/12/1206351/b0ba2e531146059beef0384f3cb02abc-700.jpg) center 50%/50% no-repeat;
  
  clip-path:circle(30%);
/*   bakcground-size: 63px 100%; */


}
```

```html
<div class="circle_clip"/>
```

Thanks for any hint

Comment: The focal point in your image isn't centered so even when the image is centered in its container, it won't look centered if the content is off to one side.

Comment: [Update to your codepen](https://codepen.io/graphixboy/pen/qBBLQxP) showing the actual center of that image.

Comment: @BryceHowitson thanks you so much to having take the time for this demo. I note that the vertical green line is little offset in the circle image comparing to the big image, what do you think about that? Anyway I will study your example and again thank you

Comment: I think it's "off" based on the way a 1px wide line is being drawn. The line is exactly centered (50% element width - 50% line width) but this can lead to a 1px line not lining up on display pixels so it can look fuzzy or strange. *Note* I didn't do anything to your background. I simply demonstrated that the image IS centered using your code.

Comment: @BryceHowitson yeah I have noted that, okay, very interesting